# Why Spark driver cache so much hadoop LocatedFileStatus when runing SQL on parquet

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm running spark job on yarn cluster , read data from parquet file and write back after anylysis. Running a while , driver will get OOM and quit. I find there is many hadoop metadata in driver(jmap -histo:live $PID | head -30).

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         45839      409413024  [B
   2:       1947930      206838976  [C
   3:       1947532       46740768  java.lang.String
   4:        142863       11429040  java.net.URI
   5:        331654       10422648  [Ljava.lang.String;
   6:        142719       10275768  org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus
   7:        134418        7527408  org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation
   8:         29856        5254656  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DatanodeInfoWithStorage
   9:        146047        4673504  scala.collection.mutable.LinkedEntry
  10:        142724        4567168  org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission
  11:         17556        4230704  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  12:        134418        3226032  [Lorg.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation;
  13:        142806        2284896  org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
  14:         16777        1865704  java.lang.Class
  15:         55624        1779968  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  16:           421        1187216  [Lscala.collection.mutable.HashEntry;
  17:         33501        1072032  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  18:         11491        1011208  java.lang.reflect.Method
```

I am running sql on hdfs parquet file ,the sql is like

```
"SELECT * FROM parquet.`/warehouse/TMP/USER`".
```

*The job will read about 1440000 hdfs files*. I suggest spark will load all hdfs file meta under /warehouse/TMP/USER in driver momery ,after doing so, spark executor will search hdfs block metadata from driver other than hdfs namenode and speed up data reading. 
I have to remove some hdfs files to complete my job ,and I am wondering that,why spark driver hold these metadata all the time ,How can I control the memory usage in spark driver?